# How to display posts within specific range?? Actioncontroller Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make Podcast pages. On the index page, I want to display **the latest podcast at the top**, **next three podcasts in the middle**, and **rest of all at the bottom of the page**

For example, I have 25 episodes and want to display like below

> 25  at the top
>
> 22, 23, 24 in the middle
>
> 21,20,19,18 ~ 1  at the bottom

My controller

```
class PodcastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_podcast, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /podcasts
  # GET /podcasts.json

  def index
    @podcasts = Podcast.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)

  end



  # GET /podcasts/1
  # GET /podcasts/1.json
  def show
    @podcasts = Podcast.all
  end

  # GET /podcasts/new
  def new
    @podcast = Podcast.new
  end

  # GET /podcasts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /podcasts
  # POST /podcasts.json
  def create
    @podcast = Podcast.new(podcast_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @podcast.save
        format.html { redirect_to @podcast, notice: 'Podcast was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @podcast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @podcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /podcasts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /podcasts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @podcast.update(podcast_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @podcast, notice: 'Podcast was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @podcast }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @podcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /podcasts/1
  # DELETE /podcasts/1.json
  def destroy
    @podcast.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to podcasts_url, notice: "#{@pocast.title} was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def find_podcast
      @podcast = Podcast.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def podcast_params
      params.require(:podcast).permit(:episode_url, :episode_title, :episode_description, :episode_audio_url, :episode_number)
    end
end
```

index.html.haml

```
%section.no-spacing
  .row   
    .columns.large-12
      %h1
        %b
          Career Daily
        %p
          Need latest news on your career? Looking for advices? You found us! Andy Moore, the host of Career Dailey, delivers you the most...


    .columns.large-12
      - @podcasts.each do |podcast|
         %h3
           = podcast.episode_number
           = podcast.episode_audio_url
           = podcast.episode_description
```

I could display the latest one, but stuck at showing three(2nd, 3rd, 4th) and rest of the pages (5th ~ all)

Appreciates your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @podcasts object contains each podcast you need to render.

In your view, `- @podcasts.each do |podcast|` is looping through all of the podcasts. Don’t loop through them all, the below will create loops for 2/3/4 and a separate one for the rest.

Use `@podcasts[1..3].each do |podcast|` to loop through the 2nd, 3rd & 4th. Then `@podcasts[4..-1].each do |podcast|` to loop through the remainder.

The above uses ruby’s array index method; to get only part of the array (all your podcasts). Have a look at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements for more on this.

For the top podcast, you don’t need a loop, just render out `@podcasts.first.episode_description` And the other attributes you want to render. Rails (maybe active record specifically) just allows `.first` as a convenient syntax for array index `[0]`

You asked earlier about 3 separate variables in your controller as an approach; you don’t want that - there is a real danger you’ll end up making 3 DB queries instead of just the one - much much slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @podcasts = Podcast.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
```

You are limiting the results to 1, just remove `limit(1)` or make it 25 with pagination.

Comment: That's for the top showing only one podcast. I want to show three after some divisions and the rest of the others after some divisions again.

Comment: The data should be in 1 variable, you can adjust the layout in the index page, like `@podcasts.first` will return the first one, then you can take the next three with `@podcasts[1..3]` then take the rest like `@podcasts[3..-1]`

Comment: so, I need to set up three different variables? Then, how do I actually call the data on the controller and index file, please?   I can't find any resources online :(

Comment: No its one variable in your controller which is `@podcasts` but remove the limitation from it, it will be an array with multiple objects, you can fetch the first only `@podcasts.first` in the index page, and display it wherever you want, then you can take the next 3 objects like this `@podcasts[1..3]` loop through them and display them in another place, and for the rest of the podcasts `@podcasts[3..-1]` .. it may be confusing but practice them in the console and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is presentation level logic, so you can extract last posts:

```
def index
  @podcasts = Podcast.order("created_at DESC").limit(25)
end
```

And then in template

```
%section.no-spacing
  .row   
    - @podcasts.each_with_index do |podcast, index|
      - if index.zero?
        - # render first
      - elsif index < 4
        - # render 2, 3, 4
      - else
        - # render rest
```

Comment: Do you mind if I ask how to render first / 2,3,4, / rest? That's what I'm stuck at.

Sorry, I'm a newbie and been struggling with this.